# C#/.NET - How to transform a form into an object in Visual Toolbox?

Tags: c#, .net

I learned how to create custom controls and make a library with these. No problem.
On my software I've various PopUp windows like the exemple below:

[image: PopUp Form]

It's possible to put this different forms on a library and use in other project with the Visual Toolbox ? Like a FontDialog for example:

[image: FontDialog Exemple]

I've found some solution on the web. But when I drop my form from the toolbox, there is display on the form. Not like a `FontDialog` who appear only on `ShowDialog()` request.

As a french guy, I think I don't have the good keywords for google the question.

Thanks !

Comment: Create [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

Comment: @JQSOFT  -  I follow the link you provide. But by the way, when I drop the CustomUserControl in an other form. The CustomUserControl is displayed on the form. I search to import my CustomUserControl and open there on `ShowCustomUserControl()` request on the code. UserControl have properties to hide there on conception ?

Comment: No Mate, You need to design your view in a UserControl, drop it in a Form and use that Form's functionalities. So you should move any Form-related code from the UserControl to the hosting Form. This way, you can use your Custom control again and again whether in the current project and others.